# List iterator error

Tags: c++, list, stl

I make stack based in std:list. Now i try to make functions for showing all elements from this stack:

I try to declare iterator:

```
void show_elements()
{
    list<T>::iterator it;
}
```

But i get error:  error: *dependent-name ‘std::list::iterator’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type*

What's wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: The standard library has `std::stack`, which provides a stack interface.  If you do want to write your own for whatever reason, consider using one of the other sequence containers (`vector` or `deque`); they offer better performance characteristics than `list` for all but a few usage scenarios.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[You need a`typename`:](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/techtalk/templates/#typename)

```
typename list<T>::iterator it;
```